# Intune API - CORS not enabled when uploading file to azure via link from creating mobileAppContentFile

Tags: javascript, azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-blob-storage, intune

I called `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps/<id>/<LOBType>/contentVersions/<content_version_id>/files`, and received the azureStorageUri from it, but when I try to upload something into it (splitting the file into chunks), I always get 403 CORS not enabled.
I add `$comp=block&blockid=<base64 block id>` to the received uri.
My header is:

```
    'x-ms-block-type': 'BlockBlob'
```

The exact error I receive is:

```
<Error>
  <Code>CorsPreflightFailure</Code>
  <Message>CORS not enabled or no matching rule found for this request.
           RequestId:ce3ea3a7-f01e-0068-24b5-2c0795000000
           Time:2018-08-05T12:10:00.6698414Z</Message>
  <MessageDetails>No CORS rules matches this request</MessageDetails>
</Error>
```

Seeing as I always get the CORS issue, I tried enabling it by following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-service-properties) page, but, when making the request, again I receive the same CORS error.
I'm running it in my browser, if it's any help.

I'm kinda stuck and don't know how to proceed now. I'd be happy for any help. Thanks! :)

Edit: When I make the same request via Postman, it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm kinda stuck and don't know how to proceed now

If you want to send a cross-origin request successfully, the request must match the CORS configuration including the request origin, headers & response headers. By default, CORS is disabled for each service. You could add the CORS setting for storage service. We could get more information about CORS from this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing--CORS--Support-for-the-Azure-Storage-Services?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

> Note: CORS is not supported for Premium Storage accounts.

We could set it from Azure portal.

[image]

> You can also use the wildcard character '*' to allow all origin domains to make requests via CORS.

Comment: We don't have a dedicated storage account. I use the link provided by the API.
The thing is, when I run it using either Postman or [this PowerShell script](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/powershell-intune-samples/tree/master/LOB_Application), everything runs fine.
And since I can't access the portal in your comment, I tried enable it via API, but still receive 403.

Comment: `The thing is, when I run it using either Postman or this PowerShell script` As you mentioned that` If you use the Postman or Powershell script that will not happen .`Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that allows restricted resources on a web page to be requested from another domain outside the domain from which the first resource was served` You could get more information about CORS from this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Comment: If you use the google chrome browser, you could have a  try to use the extension [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) to allow to your request any site with ajax from any source. Adds to response 'Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *' header

Comment: Already done that. And it's not really a viable solution for production.
I tried to add the header to the request, but it still fails. It fails in the OPTIONS request, in the preflight.

Comment: If you want to avoid the cors error. In your case, I recommand that you could call the storage api from backend such as implement it with webapi.

Comment: We need to run it from the browser. Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: If the storage account is dynamic and don't use backend way to call storage api, unfortunately, it seems that there is no way to avoid that.